# What parts of ASP.NET MVC3 will I be missing out on in VS2008?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

According to the MVC3 [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=955d593e-cbd1-4ed1-88eb-02ff79dd74d8&displaylang=en), *".NET 4, ASP.NET 4, Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 are required to use certain parts of this feature."*

What will I be missing out on if I'm still using VS2008?  Should I stick with MVC framework 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the original answer by Scott Gu, ASP.NET MVC 3 requires VS 2010 or Visual Web Developer 2010 Express

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/11/11/a-few-quick-asp-net-mvc-3-installation-notes.aspx

As .NET 4 is necessary for MVC 3, the support for VS2008 is almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

MVC3 requires .net 4, to develope with .net 4 you need Visual Studio 2010.

So to answer your question as long as you are using VS 2008, you need to stick with MVC2.